# how to install pnpm without first installing npm

Tags: windows, typescript, npm, pnpm

I am sitting in front of a completely clean windows 10 install – VS Code is installed but nothing else:

1. Is it possible to install and use pnpm without installing npm?
2. Is doing that a good thing or bad thing? context - typescript

Answer (score 1):

There's a standalone script on pnpm [installation guide](https://pnpm.js.org/en/installation.html).

```
curl -L https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer | node
```

Windows doesn't have curl, instead you can use `Invoke-WebRequest` within PowerShell for that. So probably this should work:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer | node
```

#### Update

Try downloading file instead and then executing it with node:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer -OutFile pnpm.js; node pnpm.js
```

Your second question is unclear.

Comment: Thnak you Evaldas, I had to install Node and configure IE neither which I had previously done but then got:                                                                         
 > Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer | node
  [stdin]:6
  require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new 
                                     Error("Cannot find module
                                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: My second questions was to ask if pnpm would then continue to work without npm installed?

Comment: Cool, we should add this to the pnpm docs. I did not know how to do this on Windows

Comment: I see. This is probably because node tries to run downloaded text as a string and then fails. Can you try updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using [COREPACK](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html)

```bash
corepack enable pnpm
```